# Loss for ordered multi class data in classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification, decision-trees

Assume data which is labeled $y_i \in \left\{ 1, 2, 3,  \ldots, 9, 10\right\}$.

Assume the labels are ordered, namely, given $y_i = 10$ to estimate $\hat{y}_{i} = 1$ is much worse than $\hat{y}_{i} = 9$.

I am looking for a loss function to take that into consideration and be usable both for deep learning, namely gradient friendly, and decision trees (XGBoost, Scikit-Learn).

I'd be happy even to be able to set the weighted loss by a matrix:

$$L_{i, j} = loss(y_i, \hat{y}_{j})$$

Namely the loss weight (Or multiplier) will be set by a matrix.

Is there a way to achieve this?
What other approaches would you use in that case?

Answer (score 3):

To sketch one approach, you may define the loss as:

$$ loss \left( \boldsymbol{y}, \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} \right) = \left( w + 1 \right) \operatorname{CE} \left( \boldsymbol{y}, \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} \right), \quad w \left( \boldsymbol{y}, \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} \right) = \frac{ \left| \arg \max_{i} \boldsymbol{y} - \arg \max_{i} \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} \right| }{K - 1} $$

Where:

- $K$ - The number of classes (2 for Binary Classification).
- $\boldsymbol{y}$ - A vector in $\mathbb{R}^{K}$ which is the ground truth probabilities per class.
- $\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}$ - A vector in $\mathbb{R}^{K}$ which is the estimation of probabilities per class of the classifier.
- $\operatorname{CE} \left( \cdot, \cdot \right)$ - The [Cross Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) loss function.
- $\arg \max_{i} \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}$ - Extracts the index of the class with the highest probability. Basically the class represented by the vector.

In the function $ w \left( \boldsymbol{y}, \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} \right) $ you may raise the distance between the class indices as you want.

I think it should work well for you in the context of Deep Learning.

For the matrix case, you may use the same loss as above and set:

$$ w \left( \boldsymbol{y}, \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} \right) = {L}_{\arg \max_{i} \boldsymbol{y}, \arg \max_{i} \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}} $$

Where in my convention $ \boldsymbol{y} $ and $ \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} $ are vectors of the discrete distribution over classes.

One simple extension would be:

$$ w \left( \boldsymbol{y}, \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} \right) = \frac{ {\left| \arg \max_{i} \boldsymbol{y} - \arg \max_{i} \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} \right|}^{p} }{K - 1} $$

Where $ p \geq 1 $.

Comment: Can I use arbitrary loss per pair of class? Like in the matrix?

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin, I added something about the matrix case.

Answer (score 3):

A non-deep-learning approach to this kind of problem is [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression), which serves precisely the purpose you described.

To apply the idea of ordinal regression to deep learning, there are at least 2 approaches:

- [Rank consistent ordinal regression (CORAL)](https://github.com/Raschka-research-group/coral-pytorch), a theoretically-sound formulation (see [Rank consistent ordinal regression for neural networks with application to age estimation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07884)).
- The empirical approach proposed by [Mathias Gruber - How to Perform Ordinal Regression / Classification in PyTorch](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-perform-ordinal-regression-classification-in-pytorch-361a2a095a99). The author of this approach claims that it gets better results than CORAL.

Comment: I see. Am I wrong that all those methods won't let me set the cost of the error per pair?